# How to remove microseconds from matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have been through the pylab examples and many axis formatting questions, but am still unable to remove the microseconds from the x-axis in the plot below.

Original code before trying to alter axis/tick properties and its output.

[image]

```
#filenames to be read in
file0 = 'results'         


#Get data from file strore in record array
def readIn(fileName):
    temp = DataClass()
    with open('%s.csv' % fileName) as csvfile:
        temp = mlab.csv2rec(csvfile,names = ['date', 'band','lat'])
    return temp

#plotting function(position number, x-axis data, y-axis data,
#                       filename,data type, units, y axis scale)
def iPlot(num,xaxi,yaxi,filename,types, units,scale):
    plt.subplot(2,1,num)
    plt.plot_date(xaxi,yaxi,'-')
    plt.title(filename + "--%s" % types )
    plt.ylabel(" %s  %s " % (types,units))
    plt.ylim(0,scale)
    plt.xticks(rotation=20)



# Set plot Parameters and call plot funciton
def plot():
    nameB = "Bandwidth"
    nameL = "Latency"
    unitsB = " (Mbps)"
    unitsL = "(ms)"
    scaleB = 30
    scaleL = 500

    iPlot(1,out0['date'],out0['lat'],file0,nameL,unitsL,scaleL)
    iPlot(2,out0['date'],out0['band'],file0,nameB,unitsB,scaleB)

def main():
    global out0 
    print "Creating plots..."

    out0 = readIn(file0)
    plot()

    plt.show()

main()
```

My attempt was to alter the code above by adding:

```
months   = date.MonthLocator()  # every month
days     = date.DayLocator()
hours    = date.HourLocator()
minutes    = date.MinuteLocator()
seconds   = date.SecondLocator()


def iPlot(num,xaxi,yaxi,filename,types, units,scale):
    plt.subplot(2,1,num)
    plt.plot_date(xaxi,yaxi,'-')
    plt.title(filename + "--%s" % types )
    plt.ylabel(" %s  %s " % (types,units))
    plt.ylim(0,scale)

    # Set Locators
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hours)

    majorFormatter = date.DateFormatter('%M-%D %H:%M:%S')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
    ax.autoscale_view()
```

Is the major formatter I'm setting being over written by a default on?  Is there a way to just turn off the microseconds without mucking with the rest of the format?  I am fairly unclear on where the microseconds come from as my data contains none.

Comment: Where is `ax` being set?  from `subplots(...)`?  Can you show that line?

Comment: fig,ax = plt.subplots()       Happens at very top of code

Comment: Are your Seconds floats? Could you round them down to ints for plotting?

Comment: Are you passing no arguments to `subplots`?  Is it simply `fig, ax = subplots()`?

Comment: jedwards --yes,  cphlewis-- they are datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've a couple of problems with your code. First, it doesn't work (and I mean it doesn't work even when I make all the mock sample data). Second, it's not really a minimal working example showcasing what's wrong, I can't figure out what your `date` is, I presume `matplotlib.dates`? Third I can't see your plot (your full label with the `'%M-%D` part on it as well)

Now issues I have with that is, I can't figure out how do you even get past the line with `('%M-%D %H:%M:%S')` which throws an incorrect syntax my way. (Matplotlib 1.3.1 Win7 both on python2.6.6 and 3.4). I can't see what your `ax` is, or how does your data look like, all of this can be problematic when it comes to stuff like this. Even having an overly large time span can cause ticks to "overflow" (especially when you try to put hour locators on a range of years, i.e. that throws an error at 7200 ticks I think?)

Meanwhile, here's my min working example that doesn't display the same behavior as yours.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

days     = mpl.dates.DayLocator()
hours    = mpl.dates.HourLocator()


x = []
for i in range(1, 30):
    x.append(dt.datetime(year=2000, month=1, day=i,
                             hour=int(i/3), minute=i, second=i))
y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    y.append(i)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.plot_date(x, y, "-")

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hours)

majorFormatter = mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax.autoscale_view()

plt.show()
```

[image]

(This all shouldn't probably be an answer, maybe it'll turn out it helps you, but it's too long to be a comment).

Comment: You are correct on a bunch of what you said.  After reading some of the answers/comments parts of my understanding of the plotting are fundamentally flawed...  I am going to post the full original code and plot output to clarify how my code works.

Comment: @Tom try to isolate your problem to a separate smaller script the best you can, not post the full code. If it's long, that helps even less. Apart from that, good luck!

Comment: I think I'm just missing the proper way to set ax with the way im doing the subplots

Comment: @Tom I don't see you creating an `fig` or `ax` instance anywhere up there. Notice how I did `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` so you should also do `f, axarr = plt.subplot(2, 1, m)` or even possibly a `fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)`. In the code you added you refer to `ax` instance which doesn't exist and that should result in an error. In your original example you're working with the `plt` command, which implicitly creates and then selects an `fig` and an `ax`. [See this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) code where it says `# Two subplots, the axes array is 1-d`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using subplots, don't use them.

Simply remove any mention of the `subplot()` or `subplots()` functions, then to get an axis handle you could use: `ax = plt.gca()` above any reference to `ax`.

Maybe something like:

```
...
# Set Locators
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hours)
...
```

Then, you'll get a `ValueError: Invalid format string` error -- likely because you have `%D` isn't a [valid strftime string formatting directive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).  (You probably want `%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.)  If you fix that, your plot will display with your formatter.